# PostGIS | Get degrees clockwise from north of a linestring's beginning and end

Tags: postgis, linestring, circle

I have a table full of linestrings in PostGIS. I would like to know the degrees clockwise from north of the starting point of the linestring and also of the end point.

I was thinking that maybe creating a circle with both points could help to get this two values (example: X=32º, Y=209º) but i have no clue how to achieve this....

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

St_Azimuth may be helpful. The help page shows how to generate the degrees from north. http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Azimuth.html

Comment: ST_Azimuth seems to work between separate geometries (points only), instead of along the vertices of a linestring. Or is there another way to use it?

Comment: right but the first point of the linestring can be obtained with the st_startpoint function and the endpoint with the st_endpoint.

Comment: I will get the st_centroid of the poliline and then use that point in st_azimuth with the point obtained with st_startpoint and then again with st_endpoint